# Error iniciando USB dual booth "Invalid magic number, you need to load the kernel first"

Tags: linux, instalacion

Intento instalar Pop Os como dual booth, dejé una USB como booteable con el iso correspondiente y al momento de iniciar el equipo y seleccionar iniciar con la USB aparece el mensaje:

Error: Invalid Magic Number.
Error: You need to load the kernel first.

Intenté desactivando el secure booth e intentando hacer la instalación con una USB distinta, pero no ha dado resultado.
(Tengo una laptop Asus Vivobook)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que la transferencia de la iso al usb no se ha hecho bien, creaste el usb en windows directamente o utilizaste rufus? Utiliza la herramienta rufus mejor, más rápido y te aseguras de que lo hace bien al 100%.

Comment: Los dos intentos los hice desde SO distintos para validar que no fuera error del rufus, entonces uno lo hice desde Windows con rufus y otro lo hice desde otro pc con ubuntu con la herramienta de crear disco de arranque.